# opengl 2.0 es view distance

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I've just stated learning Opengl ES 2.0 in android and I run into a problem that i don't know how to solve.
I want to create a large plane field, I created it, put on texture but here comes my problem
It doesn't draw all of it it only displays about 10 unit on the Z axe.. X i fine.
So i want to create a big square but it displays a rectangle. It is like someone took a scissors and cut it off a certaint Z coordinate.

I don't even know what part of my code should i put it here, shader ? plane coordinates ? camera settings ?

Thank you for your patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your plane is getting clipped by the frustum or viewing volume.  That is typically set by either glOrtho() or glPerspective().  Try increasing the distance between the near and far plane parameters to these functions.

If you are relying on a default frustum provided by Android, you may have to construct your own frustum, which would look something like this for glOrtho():

```
typedef struct
{
    float f0;
    float f1;
    float f2;
    float f3;
    float f4;
    float f5;
    float f6;
    float f7;
    float f8;
    float f9;
    float f10;
    float f11;
    float f12;
    float f13;
    float f14;
    float f15;
} Mat4;

void Ortho(Mat4 * pMat4, float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
{
    float rcplmr = 1.0f / (left - right);
    float rcpbmt = 1.0f / (bottom - top);
    float rcpnmf = 1.0f / (nearPlane - farPlane);

    pMat4->f0 = -2.0f * rcplmr;
    pMat4->f1 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f2 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f3 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f4 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f5 = -2.0f * rcpbmt;
    pMat4->f6 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f7 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f8 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f9 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f10 = -2.0f * rcpnmf;
    pMat4->f11 = 0.0f;
    pMat4->f12 = (right + left) * rcplmr;
    pMat4->f13 = (top + bottom) * rcpbmt;
    pMat4->f14 = (nearPlane + farPlane) * rcpnmf;
    pMat4->f15 = 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: I don't think glOrtho and glPerspective exist in ES. You are definitely right about the clipping, though.